# OnKeyPress or some type of event that happens as soon as a value has changed in a textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I'm working in C# /ASP.Net and I'm trying to figure out a way to write some code that will run as soon as a textbox's value changes.  In Access this would probably be done with a KeyPress event, but I'm using C#.  I know **nothing** about Javascript, and I know there's an OnBlur event for a textbox but it only takes Java.

Is there any way to do this using only C# code-behind and ASP.Net, or am I going to have to suck it up and teach myself Javascript?

What I want to do is determine if any change has been made to a textbox at the moment of the keystroke, and if so I need to change the "Visible" properties of two buttons so that button1 is visible and button2 is not.  If no change has been made by the time I get to the OnTextChanged event, then button2 is visible and button1 is not.

Comment: In Access you'd actually want the Change event:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821734(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: As I understand, you need an event that precedes the OnTextChanged?

Comment: Correct.  In Access, there is (in order) GotFocus, KeyPress OnChange and LostFocus.  OnTextChanged is like LostFocus.  What I need is something like KeyPress, but it has to be coded in C# code-behind because I don't know Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this that is native to Asp.Net. You will have to learn a little javascript or jQuery. For example, in native js:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt" ClientIDMode="Static" onkeyup="onEnterText()"></asp:TextBox>

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnOne" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="One" style="display:none;" />
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnTwo" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Two" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onEnterText() {
        var text = document.getElementById("txt").value,
            one = document.getElementById("btnOne"),
            two = document.getElementById("btnTwo");

        if (text.length > 0) {
            one.setAttribute("style", "display:inline;");
            two.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
        } else {
            one.setAttribute("style", "display:none;");
            two.setAttribute("style", "display:inline;");
        }
    }
</script>
```

ClientIDMode="Static" is important because it ensures that the control's ID is unchanged (Asp.Net usually creates a client id based on the control hierarchy), enabling you to find the control in javascript.

Also bear in mind that your buttons' visibility will need to be managed during postbacks to mirror the client-side logic.